# Linear space obtained from another one factoring out the constant.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a three dimensional vector space $H$, I don't understand what is the two dimensional vector space obtained from $H$ by factoring out the constants. Someone can explain me that?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you read that? What is it connected with?

Comment: Factoring out what constants?

Comment: I read that from the book Differential Equations on fractal by Strichartz page 17 point 1.3.4.

Comment: Are you referring to the projective plane, defined as the quotient of a $3$-dimensional vector space by the equivalence relation: $\,(x',y',z')\sim(x,y,z)\iff \exists \lambda\neq 0~( x',y',z')=\lambda(x,y,z)$?

Comment: I looked it up. From what I can see, I think that H is a transformation from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: "Consider the two-dimensional space obtained from $H$ by factoring out the
constants. Choose a basis for this space and find explicit $2 × 2$ matrices
$\overline{A}_i$ that represent the transformations $h → h◦F_i$ with respect to your basis"

Comment: That's the exercise. But the three dimensional space $H$  in that case is the space of harmonical functions on the Sierpinsky Gasket. Not a transfomation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question didn't include all the necessary information; luckily it was provided by the discussion between [another user](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239480/linear-space-obtained-from-another-one-factoring-out-the-constant#comment2520101_1239480) and [you](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239480/linear-space-obtained-from-another-one-factoring-out-the-constant#comment2520123_1239480).

The notion you are looking for is a quotient space.

Given a vector space $V$ over a field $k$, and a vector subspace $W\subset V$, the quotient $V/W$ space is the set of equivalent classes of elements of $v$ under the equivalent relation $v_1 \sim v_2$ iff $v_1 - v_2 \in W$. One can check that the vector space operations (scalar multiplication and vector addition) induce well-defined operations on $V/W$ to make it a vector space.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_%28linear_algebra%29) for more details.

In your case the space $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of functions (solutions to a differential equation). The subspace $W$ is the subspace of constant functions. So he is asking you to consider the space of harmonic functions ($H$) where you consider two harmonic functions to be equivalent if they only differ by a constant.